# Create new CiviCRM database...?

Tags: database

I just succesfully installed CiviCRM on our website (WordPress), I created a new DB but was not given the option to specify it during the installation process.  It seems to have installed in a DB that was already there xxxxx_demodb in which I can now see all the civicrm_xxxx tables, along with a handful of tables that look like they belong to WordPress, listed here:

- wp_commentmeta, wp_comments, wp_links, wp_options, wp_postmeta, wp_posts,
  wp_termmeta, wp_terms, wp_term_relationships, wp_term_taxonomy,
  wp_usermeta, wp_users.

Can somenoe pls confirm if these are WP or CiviCRMtables, and/or advise on how I can move the tables into a new DB and what config/ini things will need to be updated to make this work.

Or just create a whole (or use the empty one I already created) new fresh standalone DB, I have only made minor changes to the settings that I can just redo...

Thanks, Joe.

Answer (score 2):

The database tables you mentioned are wordpress CMS db tables. you would need to reinstall civicrm again and when installing it would ask for database fields where you can put in the civicrm database name and connection details. This documentation explains well the process of installing civicrm in wordpress CMS: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/